# Jmeter - How to get the min of all the timestamp's (minimum of an array)

Tags: jmeter

Have API call which returns multiple timestamp's values as:

```
[
  "2021-06-22T21:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T21:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T20:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T19:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T15:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T18:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T19:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T15:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T17:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T12:00:00+02:00",
  "2021-06-22T16:00:00+02:00"
]
```

I extract all the timestamps as:
[image]

And then convert to variables as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    
    vars.put("Times" + i, (vars.get("Times1_" + i)));
}
```

I keep all those timestamps as: Times1, Times2...Times16

What is the easiest way to get the min value of all the timestamp's, ex: `"2021-06-22T12:00:00+02:00"`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)?  It provides [sort()](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#sort) function so you can get the "min" value as simple as:

```
sort(@) | [0]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: hmm, something new for me. Is it possible to get the min() from the first 12 values?

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)

Comment: `sort(@[:12]) | [0]`

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Dmitri was helpful as always, the solution for my question was:

```
JSR223 PostProcessor
```

And inside:

```
List values = new ArrayList()


    for (int i=1; i <= 6 ; i++) { 
         values.add((vars.get('Times1_' + i) as String))
     }
    
    vars.put('min', Collections.min(values) as String)
    
    log.warn(vars.get("min"));
```